# Create parameterized test for my mojo from Java queue

Tags: java, maven, mojo

The issue is that I have a queue of test cases (Queue of queue of steps) in a list in one of the classes of my Maven plugin (Java) and I'm figuring out how to take each node of the list and put it as a parameter of a test (TestNG). Though I coded a *'Hello World'* test, it doesn't run inside my custom plugin. Can anybody tell me why, and how can I create a parameterized test inside a maven plugin?

Comment: What kind of Maven plugin are you trying to implement? Can you show the code you have? Why are you trying to make parameterized in a Mojo? You can use them in your Unit Tests without a supplemental plugin except surefire...

Comment: Surefire? But I understood that for testing a Maven plugin one must use [maven-plugin-testing-harness](http://maven.apache.org/plugin-testing/maven-plugin-testing-harness/getting-started/index.html)